# Is it true that $| \int_\gamma f|= \int_\gamma|f|$, for any closed path $\gamma$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

My guess is it's false. I try to give counter examples, I tried $f=z$,  though $|f|$ is not holomorphic the values are same. Is the result true?

Comment: the problem is unclear since the measure on RHS is not specified (could be $dz$ or $|dz|$ for example

Comment: why don't you consider a regular integral, like f(z)=z, from z=-1 to z=1

Comment: The measure is dz

Comment: then $\frac{1}{z}$ is a counterexample as LHS is $2\pi$, RHS is zero on the unit circle of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $$\left| \int_{\gamma} f \right| \le \int_\gamma |f| |dz|.$$
For a concrete example, let $\gamma$ be the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$ and $f(z) = z.$ The left hand side is $0$ but the right hand side is $2 \pi$.

As @Conrad points out, if you mean $\int |f| dz$ then you can take $f(z) = 1/z$. By the residue theorem $\int_{\gamma} f dz = 2\pi i $ whereas $\int_\gamma |f| dz = 0.$

Comment: How? It is $2\pi$

Comment: It is if the measure is $|dz|=d\theta$; it is not if the measure is $dz=izd\theta$

Comment: Yes perfect !!!